# ERROR [PackageLoader] The "@grpc/proto-loader" package is missing in e2e test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, graphql, nestjs, grpc

Hi I'm trying to write test for my login graphql service, But I have issue when I'm runnning the code. I'm using this code:

login.spec.ts

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import AppModule from './app.module';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';

const gql = '/graphql';

describe('GraphQL AppResolver (e2e) {Supertest}', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule.forRoot({})],
    }).compile();
    
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  describe(gql, () => {
    describe('login', () => {
      it('should login', () => {
        return request(app.getHttpServer())
          .post(gql)
          .send({
            operationName: "Login",
            query: `mutation Login($data: SigninInput!){
              login(dto:$data){
                user_type
                access_token
                refresh_token
                exp
                roles
                code
                messages
              }
            }`,
            variables: {
              "data": {
                "email": "eh@gmail.com", "password": "12345678"
              }
            },
          })
          .expect(200)
          .expect((res) => {
            console.log(res.body.data.login)
          });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

When i run the test I'm getting this error:

```
[Nest] 15826  - 07/31/2023, 6:26:04 PM   ERROR [PackageLoader] The "@grpc/proto-loader" package is missing. Please, make sure to install this library ($ npm install @grpc/proto-loader) to take advantage of ClientGrpcProxy.
  ●  process.exit called with "1"

 11 |   beforeAll(async () => {
    > 12 |     const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
         |                                          ^
      13 |       imports: [AppModule.forRoot({})],
      14 |     }).compile();
      15 |
```

Do somebody know what's the problem?

I tried to install @grpc/proto-loader but it did not work.

Comment: How are you running the test? How are you installing the other modules (`@nestjs/testing` and `@nestjs/common`)? How did you try to install `@grpc/proto-loader`?

Comment: `npm run test`, I'm using jest for that and I added the `"test":"jest"` to the package.json `script` ... I'm always using `npm install` and I did not use `yarn` anywhere

Comment: What happens when you `npm install @grpc/proto-loader`?

Comment: I fixed that. the problem was about jest config.

Answer (score 0):

It took me many hours to find the problem so I decided to answer my question, maybe I could help someone. The problem was about `moduleNameMapper` in jest config. I added this block of code to my jest config and now my code works perfectly:

```
"modulePaths": [
  "node_modules",
  "<rootDir>"
],
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "src/base(.*)": "<rootDir>/base/$1",
  "src/common(.*)": "<rootDir>/common/$1",
  "src/config(.*)": "<rootDir>/config/$1",
  "src/debug(.*)": "<rootDir>/debug/$1",
  "src/hexagon(.*)": "<rootDir>/hexagon/$1",
  "src/infrustructure(.*)": "<rootDir>/infrustructure/$1",
  "src/symbol": "<rootDir>/symbol",
  "src/proto(.*)": "<rootDir>/proto/$1"
  // [src/folder or file name(.*): "<rootDir>/folder or file name/$1"
}
```